# Crepant Resolutions of $\mathbb{C}^{4}/G$ for G Cyclic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

What is known about crepant resolutions of $\mathbb{C}^{4}/G$ for G cyclic? Any references for such resolutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a resolution is crepant if all discrepancies of exceptional divisors are zero.

You may find a lot of useful references and information in [M.Grab's phd thesis](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/sites/default/files/m_grab_doktorat2.pdf). For instance section 2.2 addresses discrepancy divisors of quotient singularities for $G\subseteq \mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Theorem 2.2.13 describes discrepancies of exceptional divisors in terms of the stabilizers of their general points. The case of cyclic groups should be particularly easy.

Comment: As written this is a comment, not an answer to the question. Can you perhaps add where in the thesis is the question addressed? Perhaps copy the relevant result?

Comment: @user347489 thank you for this remark. My answer was too sketchy.